# Problem loading data into SQL Server using python

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc library. It seems to be working when I load data into my local server (without password). However, when I try to load data into another server there seems to be some error.

```
# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=xxxxxx;'
                  'Database=test_preproduction;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                  'UID=xxxxxx;'
                  'PWD=xxxxxxxxx;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO test_preproduction.[dbo].[people_info] (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Column1, 
                row.Column2,
                row.Column3,
                row.Column4,
                row.Column5,
                row.Column6,
                row.Column7,
                row.Column8
                )
conn.commit()
```

I got this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'test_preproduction.dbo.people_info'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Well then, is there actually a table named `people_info` in the `dbo` schema of the database `test_preproduction` on that server? If not, then that would explain the error. You have to create a table first before you can insert to it (or else use `SELECT .. INTO`). As an aside, explicitly specifying the database name in the `INSERT` is not a good practice -- you already specified the database when you connected, and if you fail to keep the names in sync you'll get a nasty surprise.

Comment: Let the connection determine the database. Don't hardcode that into every sql statement used by your application - that makes your code more difficult (i.e., creates more work) to move to different environments.

Comment: How is that even connecting to generate a table-related error? Use `UID=...;PWD=...;` for SQL Login authentication, or `Trusted_Connection=yes;` for Domain/Windows authentication, but don't mix the two. I'm surprised it's not failing with a login error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try:
     connection.autocommit = False 
     for row in df.itertuples():
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[people_info] (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8)" "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", (row))
     connection.commit()
```

This worked for me. Since the value "row" was not called, that's why you got the error part (SQLExecDirectW) from your error message. If autocommit is True, the provided SQL statement will be committed for each and every record resulting in duplicate row entry which you might want to avoid. Hope this helps with the debugging.